# Is there a way to stop the display from turning off?

Tags: display, power-management, 11.10

I'm using the latest version of Ubuntu 11.10, and although I've disabled the lock screen options and checked the power settings, my display turns off after around ten minutes. That wouldn't be so bad, except it does it when I'm watching movies and TV shows. Is that a bug, or is there some way that I can disable that?

Comment: This DOES NOT fix this problem! I have the same issue... I have set any and all power and screen settings to NEVER turn off or dim the screen... I have also disabled the screen saver and the screen is still going blank after 10 minutes. I have also checked my BIOS to make sure that there isn't a power saving setting in there that may be overriding the OS and there are no power saving settings in my BIOS, so this is most definitely a bug in the OS. A real fix for this problem would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

From the desktop, click Power Button and choose System Settings...,

Then open Screen (icon).

Under Brightness, note that the default is set to "10 minutes". You'll probably want to change it to "Never" for your situation.

[image]